# Do you neeed to remove SASS files in final production deployment with React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, deployment, sass

Do you need to manually remove all .sass files when you build your React app since it is only the .css that's needed? Or does it do it automatically? I am using Dart Sass.

Comment: you only need to upload build folder in your production server

Answer (score 0):

.sass files get transpiled to .css, they are not supposed to be on the final build and it's done automatically depending on your bundler configuration.